# Chart CiviCRM CiviPetition results?

Tags: drupal, charts, survey, civicrm

We'd like a sort of overview report regarding our petitions in CiviCRM. It would be great to have two pie charts, one showing contacted and signed % and contacted but not signed %, and another pie chart showing the results of our one-question poll (Yes, No, Maybe).

Ideally the charting would be integrated into CiviCRM so we don't need to do custom code to get charts every time we run a poll.

I can't find anything to do this on the CiviCRM forums and my question there is unanswered.

Would this be better done in Drupal Webforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a job for a custom report template.  The issue is that you're not just looking at petition signature activities; you're comparing that against being "contacted".  CiviCRM won't know off the bat what you mean by that.  Is it receiving an email?  Having a phone call activity?  Having any activity in X campaign?

The custom report template would need to extend the activity report to include contacts who are involved in two activities: being "contacted" and signing the petition.  Really, it's not a report of petition signatures--many won't have signed anything--it's a report of being "contacted", so you'll need to be able to filter out what that is (and distinguish these activities from being contacted with a different ask).

You'll need to have the report template make joins from the "contacted" activity to the civicrm_activity_contact table, then to the same table (to find other activities the same contact is involved with), then to the civicrm_activity table again to get the petition signatures.  Once you have the basics working there, you can add in columns and filters, and after that, you can give the report a pie chart display.

Once you have all this set up (and it is a bit significant--my shop would charge for 5-10 hours of work), you could use the regular interface to pick which petition and what criteria should be used for identifying those being "contacted".  You could have a bunch of saved report instances for that single template, so you wouldn't need to write any new code unless a CiviCRM upgrade interfered with things.

Here's the reference for how to create custom report templates:
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Report-Template+Extension

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I've received similar advice on the CiviForums and I'll explore that it more detail. It seems like a basic, common report, and I am surprised no one has done this yet, or if they have they have not shared it. It might take you 5-10 hours. At my level it would probably take 40-60.